# Coding the Matrix task 1.4.10: Plot plots nothing, despite the complex numbers gathered

Tags: python, image-processing, list-comprehension, complex-numbers

The modules (plotting and image) and the sample image described in the task can be accessed here under the subheading "The Field":
http://resources.codingthematrix.com/

> Task 1.4.10: We have provided a module image with a procedure
> file2image(filename) that reads in an image stored in a file in the
> .png format. Import this procedure and invoke it, providing as
> argument the name of a file containing an image in this format,
> assigning the returned value to variable data. An example grayscale
> image, img01.png, is available for download. The value of data is a
> list of lists, and data[y][x] is the intensity of pixel (x,y). Pixel
> (0,0) is at the bottom-left of the image, and pixel (width-1,
> height-1) is at the top-right. The intensity of a pixel is a number
> between 0 (black) and 255 (white). Use a comprehension to assign to a
> list pts the set of complex numbers x + yi such that the image
> intensity of pixel (x, y) is less than 120, and plot the list pts.

Expected output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Zups.jpg

My solution (which, despite the fact I've gathered the complex numbers in the list, doesn't show anything on the graph):

```python
!pip install pypng 
from image import file2image
data = file2image('img01.png')    
data[25][25]  #output: (185, 185, 185)

from plotting import plot
pts = [x +y*1j for y in range(0, len(data)) for x in range(0, len(data[0])) 
if data[y][x][0] < 120] # outputs list of complex numbers
plot(pts, 4)
```

Plot shows nothing.

Simpler example with plotting that works:

```python
from plotting import plot
S = [2+2j, 3+2j, 1.75 + 1j, 2+1j, 2.25 + 1j, 2.5+1j, 2.75 + 1j, 3+1j, 3.25+1j]
plot(S, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

the second arg for plot is scale so use a number greater than the absolute value of the real and imaginary parts of the numbers you are plotting

also I want to refer you to the errata for this task which says:

"Task 1.4.10: image.file2image(filename) returns a representation of a color image, namely a list
of lists of 3-tuples. For the purpose of this task, you must transform it to a representation of a
grayscale image, using image.color2gray(·). Also, the pixel intensities are numbers between 0
and 255, not between 0 and 1. In this task, you should assign to pts the list of complex numbers
x + iy such that the image intensity of pixel (x, y) is less than 120."